# ASP and External CSS

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

I'm new to ASP, ASP not ASP.NET.  I've programmed before, had experience in PHP.  I have many experience with HTML and CSS.  I like to organise my files.  I know (in php file) I only have to link the external css in the  tags to style my webpages.  I assume it's the same for ASP.  It does, but not for me.

Whenever I tried to edit the style of my asp program and run it in the server it doesn't work.  I created other pages as well and same thing happened.  Whenever I used Google Chrome to see the elements, I could see my code, but when I click on the style sheet in the 'INSPECT ELEMENT' tool, it opens at the side with nothing there.  I did script the css, and tried to make the background color black.  The styling works only when I do an internal styling within the asp file between the  tags.

Does anyone know how I may solve this issue? I hate using internal css as external ones are faster and more organised.

Comment: can you add your tags that include the external css files? Also which html version are you using html 5 has changed tags slightly. They are backwards compatible but it is best to avoid the depreciated format. Also did you try refreshing the page? the most common error you will have is external files being cached and not updating properly.

Comment: in chrome open your Network tab and reload the page. This will inform you if it could find the external resources. It probably isn't being src'd properly (check all relative paths to ensure they match your directory structure).

Comment: I'm just editing the body tag, styling background and font.  I have not use HTML5 on the asp file, these will come later when the issue is solved.  I tested it on Firefox as well.  Still the same problem.  Yes I've tried refreshing the page, and the path is correct.  I looked for errors and there weren't any.  I even copy and pasted the link from a successful page to the asp page and it still didn't work.  I tried network tab and reloaded.  it showed the css and asp file and they are from the right folder.

Comment: continued.....  Its like the browser won't read my css.  When I tried to look at my css from the browser, it shows a blank sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check the following common issues:

1. Make sure your stylesheet file has a file extension of `.css`
2. Check if you have a MimeType setup for `.css` files as `text/css` in your IIS.
3. If you're returning CSS code from a `.asp` page file extension, make sure you first call `Response.ContentType = "text/css"` at the top of the page.
4. When including it in your html document make sure you're using something along the lines of the following syntax:

.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was the Mime Type problem.  Had to install it and when it's installed the style sheet works! :)

Comment: Great, you must be on some legacy host if it doen't have a mimetype of css lol. Anyways, glad you got it fixed.

Comment: You could also configure IIS to run css through the asp.dll runtime.  Therefore allowing you to write asp code in your css code.  you still need to add the content type header via asp.